# PostgreSQL SQL or PL/pgSQL query for traversing a directed graph and returning all edges found

Tags: sql, postgresql, recursion, plpgsql

I'm not particularly accustomed to generating complex SQL queries and am having difficulty in mixing my understanding of procedural languages and of set-based operations in
devising a recursive query for network traversal.  I wish to find the set of edges that lie 'upstream' of a particular node through conducting a depth first search of a directed graph (each node can have more than one upstream edge) and would ideally to implement this in SQL.

The pseudocode for what I wish to do looks like the following:

```
interesting_pipes = Pipes[]

func find_all_pipes_upstream(node n)
 if is_inlet(nodename)
    return Nil
 else
   for p in upstream_pipes:
     if p in interesting_pipes:
       return Nil
   else
     interesting_pipes.append(p)
     find_all_pipes_upstream(upstream_node(p))
```

I've already written the following functions in pure SQL:

```
upstream_pipes(node_name varchar) RETURNS SETOF "Pipes"
upstream_node(pipe_name varchar) RETURNS "Node"
is_inlet(node_name) RETURNS boolean
```

but am struggling to figure out how to manage scoping and return types
when translating the above pseudocode to either a PostgreSQL `WITH RECURSIVE` query or a PL/pgSQL function.  Most of the examples I've seen of `WITH RECURSIVE` queries have been devised for traversing back through trees where each node has just one parent.  Has anyone any tips/advise as how best to go about this?

Cheers,

Will

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html

This query will loop if the link relationships contain cycles. Because we require a "depth" output, just changing UNION ALL to UNION would not eliminate the looping. Instead we need to recognize whether we have reached the same row again while following a particular path of links. We add two columns path and cycle to the loop-prone query:

```
WITH RECURSIVE search_graph(id, link, data, depth, path, cycle) AS (
        SELECT g.id, g.link, g.data, 1,
          ARRAY[g.id],
          false
        FROM graph g
      UNION ALL
        SELECT g.id, g.link, g.data, sg.depth + 1,
          path || g.id,
          g.id = ANY(path)
        FROM graph g, search_graph sg
        WHERE g.id = sg.link AND NOT cycle
)
SELECT * FROM search_graph;
```

Comment: Thanks, Denis.  I was able to use the 'WITH RECURSIVE' query featured in the example you cited after realizing that I needed to create a view 'graph(pipe_id, downstream_node_id, upstream_node_id)', which was done as a non-recursive WITH sub-query to ensure it was only executed once for each invocation of the main graph traversal query.  My graph traversals now take 1/200 of the time that they did when I was using Python/ODBC.